# Passing array to function using pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to print array of pointer using pointer instead of array but I got this error `Segmentation fault` at runtime:

```
enter number of element:5
array[0]=1
array[1]=2
array[2]=3
array[3]=4
array[4]=5
Segmentation fault
```

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *array;
int n;

void input(int *array,int n);
void display(int *array,int n);
int sum(int *array,int n);

int main (void) {
   int result;
   printf("enter number of element:");scanf("%d",&n);
   input(array,n);  
   display(array,n);
   result=sum(array,n);
   printf("sum of array=%d",result);
   return 0;
}

void input(int *array,int n){
   int j;
   array=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
   for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        printf("array[%d]=",j);scanf("%d",array+j);
   }
}

void display(int *array,int n){
    int j;

    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        printf("%d\t",*(array+j));
    printf("\n");
}

 int sum(int *array,int n){
     int sum=0,j;

     for(j=0;j<n;j++)
       sum+=*array+j;

    return sum;
}
```

How can I fixed this code? please somebody explain me what's wrong with that code.

Comment: remove array as argument from input function. It will work

Comment: @555k Dare to explain why?

Comment: @m0skit0 Please check ans from barak manos below. Sorry I am little bit busy and just want to help him.

Comment: you are assigning the pointer after using malloc to a local function variable array, once the function returns this pointer is lost.

Answer (score 4):

Variable `array` is a local variable in function `input`.

As such, it is pointless to set it with `array = ...`, because this assignment takes effect only **inside** the function. You should typically pass its address (`&array`) to any function that needs to change it.

In your specific example, you also have a global variable `array`, so a quick solution to your problem would be to simply call function `input` without passing variable `array` as an argument:

```
void input(int n)
{
    ...
    array = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    ...
}

int main()
{
    ...
    input(n);
    ...
}
```

Note that this is a "dirty" workaround, and you should typically strive to avoid the use of global variables.

Answer (score 1):

To add the clean version to [barak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21940852/694576):

```
int input(int ** array, const size_t n)
{
  int result = 0;

  assert(NULL != array);

  (*array) = malloc(n * sizeof(**array));
  if (NULL == (*array))
  {
    result = -1;
  }
  else
  {
    size_t j;
    for(j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
      printf("array[%zu]=", j);
      scanf("%d", (*array) + j); /* still missing error checking here . */
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
if (-1 == input(&array, n))
{
  perror("input() failed");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `input()`:

```
void input(int **array,int n){
   int j;
   *array=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
   for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        printf("array[%d]=",j);scanf("%d",*array+j);
   }
}
```

Because C use pass-by-value, if you want to change the value of a variable in a function, you need to pass the address of that variable as the argument to that function.

In this case, you want to change the value of `array` in `input()` and the type of `array` is `int *`, therefore the prototype of `input()` should be something like `void input (int **array, ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

What does `*array + j` do? Does it evaluate `*array` and add `j` to it? Or does it add `j` to array and then dereference it? Would you be willing to bet $100 on it if I told you you are wrong?

Make your life and the life of anybody reading your code easier by using parentheses, or even better, write array `[j]`.

Answer (score 0):

this should do..make sure you understand what the others have said..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *array;
int n;


void input(int **array,int n);
void display(int **array,int n);
int sum(int **array,int n);

int main (void) {
int result;
printf("enter number of element:");scanf("%d",&n);
input(&array,n);
display(&array,n);
result = sum(&array,n);
printf("sum of array= %d",result);
return 0;
}

void input(int **array,int n){
int j;
*array= malloc(n*sizeof(int));
for(j=0;j<n;j++){
    printf("array[%d]=",j);
    scanf("%d",(*array)+j);
}
}

void display(int **array,int n){
int j;

for(j=0;j<n;j++){
    printf("%d\t",*((*array)+j)); // you can use array notation aswell
                                   //array[0][j] will work
}
printf("\n");
}

int sum(int **array,int n){
int sum=0,j;

for(j=0;j<n;j++){
    sum += *((*array)+j);
}
return sum;
}
```